# Running chainlink node on google cloud and accessing the node server as an operator

Tags: solidity, nodes, chainlink

I was able to access the localhost:6688 when I was running the node server, so whenever I closed the console the server will go down, so I decided to detach it by installing sleep now the server is up and running but how do I access my node dashboard as a node operator inputting my login details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Chainlink Docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/#start-the-chainlink-node)

> You can now connect to your Chainlink node's UI interface by navigating to http://localhost:6688. If using a VPS, you can create a SSH tunnel to your node for 6688:localhost:6688 to enable connectivity to the GUI. Typically this is done with `ssh -i $KEY $USER@$REMOTE-IP -L 6688:localhost:6688 -N`. A SSH tunnel is recommended over opening up ports specific to the Chainlink node to be public facing.

For example, if you're using google cloud, you'd first "login" with:

```
gcloud auth login
```

And then the command to ssh into the node after you login:

```bash
gcloud compute --project "YOUR_PROJECT" ssh --zone "ZONE_OF_NODE" "VM_NAME" -- -L 6688:localhost:6688
```